# How to fix scanf function being ignored

Tags: c

I'm trying to save 4 characters in one unsigned int using bitwise operator. However, it just skips scanf and prints next message. Here's my code:

```
printf("1st: ");
scanf("%c", &a);

printf("2nd: ");
scanf("%c", &b);

printf("3rd: ");
scanf("%c", &c);

printf("4th: ");
scanf("%c", &d);

num = a;
num |= b << 8;
num |= c << 16;
num |= d << 24;

printf("result: %x\n", num);
```

I expected the output of

```
1st: a
2nd: b
3rd: c
4th: d
result: 64636261
```

but actual output was

```
1st: a
2nd: 3rd: b
4th: result: a620a61
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have 2 large parts to your behaviour - the input of variables, and the concatenation of all (4) values into your num variable.  Remove the scanf() declarations, and get this working using just declared variables (char a = 'a', etc) - Then focus on including scanf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing `Enter` key is also considered a new character or `\n`. That's why `b` goes to `c` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop and look at what your resultant variable *num* contains:

0A 62 0A 61

and recognize that Character 0x0A is **Line-Feed** Then you'll realize that you are dealing with 4 characters.  You need to remove the Linefeed character from your Scanf buffer before retrieving each new character (otherwise its still there)